# Different types for Indexer's getter and setter

Tags: c#, indexer

I want an Indexer but types of the setter and the getter should be different.

```
public Foo this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        return FindFoo(key);
    }
}
public Bar this[string key]
{
    set
    {
        DoMagic(key, value);
    }
}
```

When I try:

```
myClass["hello"] = coolBar;
```

It says: *The call is ambiguous*

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want an Indexer but types of the setter and the getter should be different.

You can't do that, basically - not when the two indexers have the same signature.

Even if you *could*, I'd say it would be a pretty odd design, which would surprise users of your API.

The relevant bit of the C# specification is section 10.9:

> The signature of an indexer must differ from the signatures of all other indexers declared in the same class.

Comment: Jon, I always wondering how is this possible you can find that fast which section you looking for in C# Specification? Do you memorized all specification :) ?

Comment: @SonerGönül: I searched for "indexer" in the table of contents - it wasn't really that hard :) (I didn't have the reference in the first version - that was edited in.)